# Swift: guard let vs if let

Tags: swift, swift2, option-type, conventions, control-flow

I have been reading about Optionals in Swift, and I have seen examples where `if let` is used to check if an Optional holds a value, and in case it does – do something with the unwrapped value.

However, I have seen that in Swift 2.0 the keyword `guard let` is used mostly. I wonder whether `if let` has been removed from Swift 2.0 or if it still possible to be used.

Should I change my programs that contain `if let` to `guard let`?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

`if let` and `guard let` serve similar, but distinct purposes.

The "else" case of `guard` must exit the current scope. Generally that means it must call `return` or abort the program. `guard` is used to provide early return without requiring nesting of the rest of the function.

`if let` nests its scope, and does not require anything special of it. It can `return` or not.

In general, if the `if-let` block was going to be the rest of the function, or its `else` clause would have a `return` or abort in it, then you should be using `guard` instead. This often means (at least in my experience), when in doubt, `guard` is usually the better answer. But there are plenty of situations where `if let` still is appropriate.

Comment: Use `if let` when the `non-nil` case is valid. Use `guard` when the `nil` case represents some sort of error.

Comment: @BallpointBen I disagree with that. There are many cases where `guard` is appropriate even if there is no error. Sometimes it just means there's nothing to do. For example, a `positionTitle` method might `guard if let title = title else {return}`. Title may be optional, in which case this isn't an error. But `guard let` is still appropriate.

Comment: Yeah; I meant guard let in the comment.

Comment: in other words, "guard let" is used when the code is 99% sure of not using the else conditional; in the other hand,  "if let" when the code is 50 - 50(example) to use else condition.

Comment: The variable bound by `if let` is only visible **inside** `if let` scope. The variable bound by `guard let` is visible afterwards. So it makes sense to use guard to bind optional values also.

Comment: Something like ```if ! let``` would have been just as good without having us to wrap our heads around this guard thing. Saves one special word. I often think Swift is badly over-engineered.

Answer (score 159):

### Guard can improve *clarity*

When you use guard you have a much **higher** expectancy for the guard to *succeed* and it's somewhat important that if it doesn't succeed, then you just want to exit scope *early*. Like you guard to see if a file/image exists, if an array isEmpty or not.

```
func icon() -> UIImage {
    guard let image = UIImage(named: "Photo") else {
        return UIImage(named: "Default")! //This is your fallback
    }
    return image //-----------------you're always expecting/hoping this to happen
}
```

If you write the above code with if-let it conveys to the reading developer that it's more of a 50-50. But if you use guard you add *clarity* to your code and it implies I expect this to work 95% of the time...if it ever failed, I don't know why it would; it's very unlikely...but then just use this default image instead or perhaps just assert with a meaningful message describing what went wrong!

> - Avoid `guard`s when they create side effects, guards are to be used as a **natural** flow. Avoid guards when `else` clauses introduce side effects.
>   Guards establish **required** conditions for code to execute properly,
>   offering [early exit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID525)
> - When you perform significant computation in the positive branch, refactor from `if` to a `guard` statement and returns the fallback value
>   in the `else` clause

> <sub>**From:** [Erica Sadun's Swift Style book](https://pragprog.com/book/esswift/swift-style)</sub>

Also as a result of the above suggestions and clean code, it's more *likely* you will want/need to add assertions into *failed* guard statements, it just improves readability and makes it clear to other developers what you were expecting.

> ```
> guard​ ​let​ image = ​UIImage​(named: selectedImageName) else { // YESSSSSS
>      assertionFailure(​"Missing ​​\(​selectedImageName​)​​ asset"​) 
>      return
> } 
>
> guard​ ​let​ image = ​UIImage​(named: selectedImageName) else { // NOOOOOOO
> ​     ​return 
> }
> ```
>
> <sub>**From:** [Erica Sadun's Swift Style book](https://pragprog.com/book/esswift/swift-style) + some modifications</sub>

<sub>(you won't use asserts/preconditions for `if-let`s. It just doesn't seem right)</sub>

Using guards also help you improve clarity by *avoiding pyramid* of doom. See [Nitin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38356532/5175709).

### Guard keeps code that handles a violated requirement next to the requirement

To be clear, `guard` isn't always about success vs failure. The more generic way to see it is about handling a violated requirement vs process code that isn't violated.

example:

```
func getImage(completion: (image: Image)? -> Void) {
   guard cache["image1"] == false else {
      completion(cache["image1"]!)
   }
   downloadAndStore("image1") { image in 
       completion(image)
   }
}
```

In the above the requirement is for the image to not be present in cache. If the image is present then our requirement is violated. We return early. As you can see we also handle the violated code path, right next to its requirement i.e. the structure is not:

```
if requirement {
   . 
   . 
   ten lines of code
   . 
   . 
} else {
   handle requirement
}
```

The [Swift Docs on Control Flow](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#) explain the idea behind that:

> Using a guard statement for requirements improves the readability of
> your code, compared to doing the same check with an if statement.
>
> - It lets you write the code that’s typically executed without wrapping it in an else block
> - it lets you keep the code that handles a violated requirement next to the requirement.

---

### Guard avoids nesting by creating a *new* variable in the current scope

There is one important difference that I believe no one has explained well.

Both `guard let` and `if let` *unwrap* the variable however

With `guard let` you **are creating** a new variable that will *exist* in the current scope.

With `if let` you’re only creating a new variable **inside** the code block.

**`guard let:`**

```
func someFunc(blog: String?) {
    
    guard let blogName = blog else {
        print("some ErrorMessage")
        print(blogName) // will create an error Because blogName isn't defined yet
        return
    }
    print(blogName) // You can access it here ie AFTER the guard statement!!
    
    //And if I decided to do 'another' guard let with the same name ie 'blogName' then I would create an error!
    guard let blogName = blog else { // errorLine: Definition Conflicts with previous value.
        print(" Some errorMessage")
        return
    }
    print(blogName)
}
```

**`if-let:`**

```
func someFunc(blog: String?) {
    
    
    if let blogName1 = blog {
        print(blogName1) // You can only access it inside the code block. Outside code block it doesn't exist!
    }
    if let blogName1 = blog { // No Error at this line! Because blogName only exists inside the code block ie {}
        print(blogName1)
    }
}
```

For more info on `if let` do see: [Why redeclaration of optional binding doesn't create an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215914/why-doesnt-redeclaration-of-optional-binding-create-an-error/39215995#39215995)

---

### Guard requires *scope exiting*

(Also mentioned in Rob Napier's answer) :

You MUST have **`guard`** defined *inside* a func. It's major purpose is to abort/return/exit scope, *if* a condition isn't met:

```
var str : String?

guard let blogName1 = str else {
    print("some error")
    return // Error: Return invalid outside of a func
}
print (blogName1)
```

For **`if let`** you don't need to have it inside any func:

```
var str : String?    
if let blogName1 = str {
   print(blogName1) // You don't get any errors!
}
```

---

### `guard` vs `if`

It's worth noting that it's more appropriate to see this question as `guard let` vs `if let` and `guard` vs `if`.

A standalone `if` doesn't do any unwrapping, neither does a standalone `guard`. See example below. It doesn't exit early if a value is `nil`. There are NO optional values. It just exits early if a condition isn't met.

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]
func subscript(at index: Int) -> String?{
   guard index > 0, index < array.count  else { return nil} // exit early with bad index
   return array[index]
}
```

Answer (score 58):

When to use `if-let` and when to use `guard` is often a question of style.

Say you have `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int` and an optional array of items (`var optionalArray: [SomeType]?`), and you need to return either `0` if the array is `nil` (not-set) or the `count` if the array has a value (is set).

You could implement it like this using **`if-let`**:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if let array = optionalArray {
            return array.count
        }
        return 0
    }
```

or like this using **`guard`**:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        guard let array = optionalArray else {
            return 0
        }
        return array.count
    }
```

The examples are functionally identical.

Where `guard` really shines is when you have a task like validating data, and you want the function to fail early if anything is wrong.

Instead of nesting a bunch of `if-let`s as you get closer to finishing validation, the "success path" and the now successfully bound optionals are all in the main scope of the method, because the failure paths have all returned already.

Comment: Concise and clear

Comment: I get the idea, but we would generally just do `return optionalArray?.count ?? 0`, with no `if let` or `guard let` necessary.

Comment: @Rob this is a simplified example with one condition. When there are multiple conditions you can do a gauntlet of guard condition after guard condition, rejecting the invalid cases and only letting the valid case get through to the final return statement. This should make for clearer code than a bunch of nested if statements.

Comment: Agreed. No offense intended. Just an observation for future readers.

Answer (score 41):

I'll try to explain the usefulness of guard statements with some (unoptimized) code.

You have a UI where you are validating text fields for user registration with first name, last name, email, phone and password.

If any textField is not containing valid text, it should make that field firstResponder.

here is the unoptimized code:

```
//pyramid of doom

func validateFieldsAndContinueRegistration() {
    if let firstNameString = firstName.text where firstNameString.characters.count > 0{
        if let lastNameString = lastName.text where lastNameString.characters.count > 0{
            if let emailString = email.text where emailString.characters.count > 3 && emailString.containsString("@") && emailString.containsString(".") {
                if let passwordString = password.text where passwordString.characters.count > 7{
                    // all text fields have valid text
                    let accountModel = AccountModel()
                    accountModel.firstName = firstNameString
                    accountModel.lastName = lastNameString
                    accountModel.email = emailString
                    accountModel.password = passwordString
                    APIHandler.sharedInstance.registerUser(accountModel)
                } else {
                    password.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
            } else {
                email.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        } else {
            lastName.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    } else {
        firstName.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

You can see above, that all the strings (firstNameString, lastNameString etc) are accessible only within the scope of the if statement. so it creates this "pyramid of doom" and has many issues with it, including readability and ease of moving things around (if the fields' order is altered, you have to rewrite most of this code)

With the guard statement (in the code below), you can see that these strings are available outside the `{}` and are made use of, if all fields are valid.

```
// guard let no pyramid of doom
func validateFieldsAndContinueRegistration() {
    
guard let firstNameString = firstName.text, firstNameString.characters.count > 0 else {
            firstName.becomeFirstResponder()
            return
        }
guard let lastNameString = lastName.text, lastNameString.characters.count > 0 else {
            lastName.becomeFirstResponder()
            return
        }
guard let emailString = email.text, 
        emailString.characters.count > 3,
        emailString.containsString("@"),
        emailString.containsString(".") else {
            email.becomeFirstResponder()
            return
        }
guard let passwordString = password.text, passwordString.characters.count > 7 else {
            password.becomeFirstResponder()
            return
        }

// all text fields have valid text
    let accountModel = AccountModel()
    accountModel.firstName = firstNameString
    accountModel.lastName = lastNameString
    accountModel.email = emailString
    accountModel.password = passwordString
    APIHandler.sharedInstance.registerUser(accountModel)
}
```

If the order of the fields changes, just move respective lines of code up or down, and you are good to go.

This is a very simple explanation and a use case. Hope this helps!

Edits:

2023: Code updated for newer swift syntax without using `guard-let-where`

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say thank you on here but THANK YOU. This really helped me to understand guards!

Comment: the main answer was probably during the days of Swift 2. Updated! if anyone's curious see this explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41498346/503527

Answer (score 23):

Basic Difference

#### Guard let

1. Early exist process from the scope
2. Require scope existing like `return`, `throw` etc.
3. Create a new variable that can be accessed outside the scope.

#### if let

1. Can not access outside the scope.
2. no need for `return` statement. But we can write

NOTE: Both are used to unwrap the Optional variable.

Answer (score 7):

The clearest explanation I saw was in the [Github Swift Style Guide](https://github.com/github/swift-style-guide#return-and-break-early):

`if` adds a level of depth:

```
if n.isNumber {
    // Use n here
} else {
    return
}
```

`guard` doesn't:

```
guard n.isNumber else {
    return
}
// Use n here
```

Answer (score 7):

## guard let vs if let

```
func anyValue(_ value:String?) -> String {
    
    guard let string = value else {
        return ""
    }
    
    return string
}

func anyValue(_ value:String?) -> String {
    
    if let string = value {
        return string
    }
    
    return ""
}
```

Comment: This trivial example is better written without either `if let` or `guard let`. Just write `return value ?? ""`.

Answer (score 5):

[**guard**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html)

> - A `guard` statement is used to transfer program control out of a scope
>     if one or more conditions aren’t met.
> - The value of any condition in a `guard` statement must be of type `Bool`
>     or a type bridged to `Bool`. The condition can also be an optional
>     binding declaration.

A guard statement has the following form:

```
guard condition else {
    //Generally return
}
```

[**if let**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

> - Also popular as [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).
> - For accessing optional object we use `if let`.

```
if let roomCount = optionalValue {
    print("roomCount available")
} else {
    print("roomCount is nil")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I learnt this from swift with Bob..

**Typical Else-If**

```
 func checkDrinkingAge() {
      let canDrink = true

     if canDrink {
        print("You may enter")
       // More Code
        // More Code
      // More Code

         } else {
         // More Code
    // More Code
    // More Code
    print("Let me take you to the jail")
          }
     }
```

**Issues with Else-If**

1. Nested brackets
2. Have to read every line to spot the error message

**Guard Statement**
A guard block only runs if the condition is false, and it will exit out of the function through return. If the condition is true, Swift ignores the guard block. It provides an early exit and fewer brackets.+

```
func checkDrinkProgram() {
       let iCanDrink = true

           guard iCanDrink else {
        // if iCanDrink == false, run this block
         print("Let's me take you to the jail")
          return
        }

         print("You may drink")
           // You may move on
                  // Come on.
                 // You may leave
                // You don't need to read this.
                 // Only one bracket on the bottom: feeling zen.
       }
```

**Unwrap Optionals with Else-If**

A guard statement is not only useful for replacing a typical conditional block with an else-if statement, but also great for unwrapping optionals by minimizing the number of brackets. To compare, let's first begin how to unwrap multiple optionals with else-if.
First, let us create three optionals that will be unwrapped.

```
var publicName: String? = "Bob Lee"
var publicPhoto: String? = "Bob's Face"
var publicAge: Int? = nil
```

**The Worst Nightmare**

```
func unwrapOneByOne() {
         if let name = publicName {
              if let photo = publicPhoto {
                     if let age = publicAge {
                        print("Bob: \(name), \(photo), \(age)")
                                  } else {
                          print("age is mising")
                           }
                  } else {
                      print("photo is missing")
                         }
                  } else {
                        print("name is missing")
                         }
                  }
```

The code above certainly works but violates the DRY principle. It's atrocious. Let us break it down.+

**Slightly Better**
The code below is more readable than above.+

```
func unwrapBetter() {
         if let name = publicName {
       print("Yes name")
                   } else {
               print("No name")
        return
      }

         if let photo = publicPhoto {
             print("Yes photo")
            } else {
           print("No photo")
       return
             }

        if let age = publicAge {
            print("Yes age")
                      } else {
                print("No age")
            return
                           }
     }
```

**Unwrap with Guard**
The else-if statements can be replaced with guard.+

```
 func unwrapOneByOneWithGuard() {
             guard let name = publicName else {
                  print("Name missing")
              return
                                        }

              guard let photo = publicPhoto else {
              print("Photo missing")
                return
                                            }

                  guard let age = publicAge else {
                   print("Age missing")
                                     return
                                                 }
                 print(name)
                 print(photo)
                 print(age)
         }
```

**Unwrap Multiple Optionals with Else-If**
So far, you've been unwrapping optionals one by one. Swift allows us to unwrap multiple optionals at once. If one of them contains nil, it will execute the else block.

```
func unwrap() {
  if let name = publicName, let photo = publicPhoto, let age = publicAge {
    print("Your name is \(name). I see your face right here, \(photo), you are \(age)")
  } else {
    // if any one of those is missing
    print("Something is missing")
  }
}
```

> Be aware that when you unwrap multiple optionals at once, you can't identify which contains nil

**Unwrap Multiple Optionals with Guard**
Of course, we should use guard over else-if.+

```
func unwrapWithGuard() {
  guard let name = publicName, let photo = publicPhoto, let age = publicAge else {
    // if one or two of the variables contain "nil"
    print("Something is missing")
    return
  }

  print("Your name is \(name). I see your, \(photo). You are \(age).")
  // Animation Logic
  // Networking
  // More Code, but still zen
}
```

Comment: please go back and fix your code formatting / indentation!

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between guard and if statements in swift are:

- The if statement is used to run code when a condition is met.
- The guard statement is used to run code when a condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question, `if let` is still supported.

But `guard let` is intended for cleaner code to handle the “early exit” scenario. This is especially useful where the `else` clause is often just a few lines to handle the “I don’t need to proceed” logic. The rest of the function can then focus on the “happy path” having gotten the assumptions/prerequisites behind you. As the [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/controlflow#Early-Exit) says:

> **Early exit**
>
> A `guard` statement, like an `if` statement, executes statements depending on the Boolean value of an expression. You use a `guard` statement to require that a condition must be `true` in order for the code after the `guard` statement to be executed. Unlike an `if` statement, a `guard` statement always has an `else` clause — the code inside the `else` clause is executed if the condition isn’t `true`.
>
> ```swift
> func greet(person: [String: String]) {
>     guard let name = person["name"] else {
>         return
>     }
>
>     print("Hello \(name)!")
>
>     guard let location = person["location"] else {
>         print("I hope the weather is nice near you.")
>         return
>     }
>
>     print("I hope the weather is nice in \(location).")
> }
>
> greet(person: ["name": "John"])
> // Prints "Hello John!"
> // Prints "I hope the weather is nice near you."
> greet(person: ["name": "Jane", "location": "Cupertino"])
> // Prints "Hello Jane!"
> // Prints "I hope the weather is nice in Cupertino."
> ```
>
> If the `guard` statement’s condition is met, code execution continues after the `guard` statement’s closing brace. Any variables or constants that were assigned values using an optional binding as part of the condition are available for the rest of the code block that the `guard` statement appears in.
>
> If that condition isn’t met, the code inside the `else` branch is executed. That branch must transfer control to exit the code block in which the `guard` statement appears. It can do this with a control transfer statement such as `return`, `break`, `continue`, or `throw`, or it can call a function or method that doesn’t return, such as `fatalError(_:file:line:)`.
>
> Using a `guard` statement for requirements improves the readability of your code, compared to doing the same check with an `if` statement. It lets you write the code that’s typically executed without wrapping it in an `else` block, and it lets you keep the code that handles a violated requirement next to the requirement.

In short, `guard` offers the following `early exit` benefits:

1. It keeps the “test” and the “failure handling code” right next to each other, making it easier to reason about our code.
2. The compiler will warn you if you accidentally neglect to `return` (or `throw` or some other type of exit) inside the `else` clause.
3. It eliminates a lot of nested braces that you can sometimes have if you have one or more `if` clauses for what is often the standard flow within the function.

But where appropriate, feel free to use `if let`. Both `guard let` and `if let` are supported. For more information, see the [control flow](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/controlflow) section of *The Swift Programming Language.*