# Swift language: nil check, and if so instantiate new object

Tags: swift, initialization

Is there any way I can simplify this:

```
var unloadedImagesRows = [String:[Int]]()

private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
    if unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] == nil {
                    unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] = [Int]()
    }
    unloadedImagesRows[forLocation]!.append(row)
}
```

Doesn't Swift have an easy way to check for `nil`, and if so, create a new object, and all subsequent uses refers to the object?

Comment: Pretty sure your answer is the most simple swift has to offer. All the others here seem to be less simple and/or efficient. I dug for more than an hour on this and do not think there is a simpler way to express this.

Comment: Do you know of an example from another language that does this better? I am curious to know what inspired this question and if there is another way from another language, maybe propose a similar feature addition to Swift open source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simplify it into just one line:

```
private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
    unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] = (unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] ?? []) + [row]
}
```

Comment: So sweet! I was trying so hard to figure that out! Though it had to be +=... Nice work!

Answer (score 2):

```
var unloadedImagesRows = [String:[Int]]()

// if let
private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
    if let _ = unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] {

    } else {
        unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] = [Int]()
    }
    unloadedImagesRows[forLocation]!.append(row)
}

// guard let
private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
    guard let _ = unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] else {
        unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] = [Int]()
        return addToUnloadedImagesRow(row, forLocation: forLocation)
    }

    unloadedImagesRows[forLocation]!.append(row)
}

// nil coalescing
private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
    var b = unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] ?? [Int]()
    b.append(row)
    unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] = b
}
```

Comment: It looks like nil coalescing can only be used in one way because someone got the same answer I have for that one. Apparently he beat me to it while I was editing/working it out in a playground. Upvote!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a helper operator for nil checks and use it like below.

```
infix operator ?= { associativity left precedence 160 }

func ?=<T: Any>(inout left: T?, right: T) -> T {
    if let left = left {
        return left
    } else {
        left = right
        return left!
    }
}
```

Here you will be able to use it like `unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] ?= [Int]()` if empty

```
var unloadedImagesRows = [String:[Int]]()

private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
    unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] ?= [Int]()
    unloadedImagesRows[forLocation]!.append(row)
}

addToUnloadedImagesRow(1, forLocation: "This is something")

print(unloadedImagesRows) // "["This is something": [1]]\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid `if` or `guard` you could try the [nil coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72).

```
private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
    var rowsForLocation = unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] ?? [Int]();
    rowsForLocation.append(row)
    unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] = rowsForLocation
}
```

**Note:** *This might not be very efficient since you have to re-assign the array to the dictionary. I'm not sure if this will result in a full copy of the array.*

Answer (score 1):

you can use if let or guard statement

```
  private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
      if let a = unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] as? [Int] {
           //...success block
      }
  }
```

or use guard statement

```
  private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
      guard let a = unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] else {
           return
      }
      //...
  }
```

for more info. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256834/swift-2-0-guard-vs-if-let)

Answer (score 1):

You can check it as follow.

```
private func addToUnloadedImagesRow(row: Int, forLocation:String!) {
    if let image = unloadedImagesRows[forLocation] {
                //it is not nil
    } else {
        //it is nil
    }

}
```