# Creating & adding buttons to scrollview dynamically

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code that creates buttons based on the fetched data. After buttons are created they get added to a scrollview.
And they should display horizontally.

I can confirm that there is data but it shows weird things in simulator (see attached screenshot). What is wrong in my implementation?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchRecipeCategory()

    for var i = 0; i < self.category.count; i++ {
        let frame1 = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20 + (index * 45), width: 45, height: 45 )
        let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
        button.setTitle("\(category[i].name)", forState: .Normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.categoryScrollView.addSubview(button)

    }
    print(category[0].name)
}
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like it showing `Optional("yourData")`. have you tried to unwrap it?

Comment: Good catch but overlapping issue still remains. How can I spread it horizontally in an equal distribution?

Comment: You should edit your question and state that there is overlapping issue.

Comment: Use a `UIStackView` to space items equally either horizontally or vertically.

Comment: To spread it horizontally, modify `x` instead of `y`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use different `y frame` value for each button. Your button creation is using `index` for its y frame and you did not increment it.

Since your are using for loop, you could use `i` value for it.

```
let frame1 = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20 + (i * 45), width: 45, height: 45 )
```

this code will create vertical list of button. If you want to list your button horizontally, change `x frame` value for each button

```
let frame1 = CGRect(x: 20 + (i * 45), y: 20, width: 45, height: 45 )
```

As for your screenshot, it looks like that the button title is set to `Optional("data")`. if you really sure that your data source contains data, you could simply unwrap it for your button title. Better if you use optional binding for it.

Comment: Thanks. What is optional binding? like `if let _ = value {}` or guard?

Comment: using `if let` should be sufficient in your case. If you are interested in the comparison between those two, you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256834/swift-2-0-guard-vs-if-let