# Using guard keyword

Tags: swift

I have encountered numerous situations where a coder have used the guard keyword. And then later, in a seemingly almost identical situation the same coder in the same code does not use the guard keyword. I am aware that this may be a stupid question, so please don't bash it. When should I use the guard keyword and where shouldn't I?

Here is an example (there are many more). This is part of a script that is requesting data form an API.

```
    //Here I am using guard
    guard let json = json else {

        //Now I am not using guard
        if let error = error {
            completion(.Failure(error))
        } else {
            //Error handling
        }
        return
    }
```

Why not use the:

```
if let var1 = var1 {
    //Keep on going
} else {
    //Don't crash
}
```

syntax all the time instead of the guard syntax? At first glance it even seems to have more functionality, but I am certain that does not have to be the case.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: You've neglected to ask a question.

Comment: I realized that, I am editing as fast as I can, hold on

Comment: Is this what you are asking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256834/swift-2-0-guard-vs-if-let

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One great benefit of the guard statement is that you know that if the condition is not satisfied then the execution flow gets stopped.

This is important for several reasons

### Unwrapping

You can define unwrapped values which don't need a new scope `{ ... }` to be available

```
func next(num:Int?) -> Int? {
    guard let num = num else { return nil }
    return num + 1
}
```

### Readability

When you read the code you know that if the `guard` condition is not satisfied then the following lines won't be executed.

### Semantics

You know a `guard` statement is there to check conditions required for the following block of code.

### But I can replace every `guard` with an `if`

Sure. We could also replace every `while` and `for` with a `goto` in some languages. And we could always replace recursion with iteration (and viceversa).
But this doesn't necessarily means it is always a good idea.

Despite we can implement some behaviours with more then one programming "tool", we should still use the one that better fits that specific scenario.

Comment: Apple notes one of the benefits of guard is that you don't have cascades of nested ifs driving the code off to the right side