# Why doesn't redeclaration of 'optional binding' create an error?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, option-type

I am doing this in Playground, but I am not getting any error. Am I not recreating constant `range`? Is it happening in 2 different scopes? What's happening in the background that makes this *not* an error?

```
if let range = add1.rangeOfString(", ") {
    print(add1.substringToIndex(range.startIndex))
    print (range)
}

if let range = add1.rangeOfString(", ") {
    print(add1.substringToIndex(range.startIndex))
    print (range)
}
```

Comment: *Conditional binding enables you to apply a cast, test the resulting optional, and then bind unwrapped values to a local variable*. See [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2469047&seqNum=2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables introduced with Optional binding of `if-let` is local after the `let`-clause till the end of true-case code block.

So, yes. Your two `range` reside *in 2 different scopes*.

(`guard-let` is another thing.)

Comment: **1)** Can you explain why is it created that way? I couldn't find anything on Apple documentation. What's the underlying mechanism for this? **2)** And as a tangential question does. Is statement in the `{}` basically a completion handler?

Comment: @Honey, 1) if-let is a combination of non-nil checking and declaring non-nil (unwrapped) variables. Something similar to `if something != nil {let unwrappedSomething = something!;...}`. The introduced variable should be in the context where `something != nil`. But, that's true, Apple's documentation lacks detailed description of many important features of Swift.

Comment: @Honey, 2) `{}` notation bound with `if`, `while`, `do`... are called "code block".  It bundles some amount of executable statements, and also introduces new scope for local variables. `{}` in a context of "expression" is called "closure expression" (or "closure literal", many call it simply "closure"), which you are calling "completion handler".  "Closure"s can be stored in variables, passed to methods, but "code block" is a syntactic thing which cannot be separated from `if` (or some others).

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the non-nil and (finally understood after months) closure sytanx which made me observant of the `{}` but your clarifications made it much better.

Comment: I even added this line: `let range = "11" `into the if-let *code block* and still didn't get any error. Why?

Comment: In Swift, local declaration in a code block can "shadow" outer declarations. For example, `do {let a = 1; do {let a = "c"; do {let a = 0..<2}}}` is valid. Optional binding is a sort of hidden block, so you can shadow the declarations.