# Guard vs if-let

Tags: ios, swift3, guard

```
let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest)
    { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    guard error == nil else {
      print("Error while fetching remote rooms: \(error)")
      return
    }
```

Is the below block can be alternative of the above one?

```
let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest)
    { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let myerror = error! {
      print("Error while fetching remote rooms: \(myerror)")
      return
    }
```

Comment: Have a look into this : [Guard vs if-let](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256834/swift-2-0-guard-vs-if-let)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256834/swift-2-0-guard-vs-if-let

Comment: Regardless of whether this is a duplicate or not, force-unwrapping `error` in `if let myerror = error!` is simply wrong.  The point of optional-binding is to test whether a value is `nil` or not before using it.  The `if let` block is going to crash at some point.

Comment: Can you suggest me the correct if-let code for this corresponding guard?

Comment: `if let data = data { print(data.count) } else if let error = error { print(error) }`

Comment: Using guard `guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }`

Answer (score 1):

No, this would be the correct "guard let" alternative.

```
let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Error while fetching remote rooms: \(error)")
        return
    }

    // guard passed, thus there is no error
}
```