# Swift: guard let and where - the priority

Tags: swift

Sometimes, I want to use `guard` combined with `let` & `where` to simplify my code. But I wonder what's the priority of let and where. For example:

```
class Person {
    func check() -> Bool? {
        print("checking")
        return nil
    }
}

func test(dont: Bool) {
    let person = Person()
    guard let check = person.check() where dont else {
        print("should not check")
        return
    }
    print("result: \(check)")
}


test(false)
```

As you can see the console result, printed output are:

- checking
- should not check

For the condition of `let check = person.check() where dont` in `guard <condition> else { }` syntax, even the expression in `where` doesn't relate to the results of expression in `let`, Swift seems to execute `let` first then check `where` later. Sometimes in my code, `let` optional binding takes lots of calculation and `where` is only a simple condition without relying on `let` results, should I move the `where` out of `guard`? Or I'm wrong about the priority or let & where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, in your **Swift 2** code

```
guard let check = person.check() where dont else { }
```

the conditional binding `let check = ...` is checked first, and only if that succeeds, the boolean condition `dont` is checked. You can use

```
guard dont, let check = person.check() else { }
```

to check the boolean condition first.

This "asymmetry" in the syntax has been removed in **Swift 3:**
All guard clauses are separated by commas and the
`where` keyword is not used anymore. So you have

```
guard let check = person.check(), dont else { }
// or
guard dont, let check = person.check() else { }
```

The conditions are checked from left to right with short-circuiting,
i.e. if one condition fails then the else-block is executed without
checking the remaining conditions.