# What is the proper use of guard when testing for the existence of a property

Tags: swift

In my code I am being passed a dictionary. That dictionary can contain an error string. Like this

```
func handleSomething(_ json: [String: Any]) -> (Bool, String?) {
    if let error = json["error"] as? String {
        print("I have an error: \(error)")
        return (false, error)
    }
    ...
    return (true, nil)
}
```

I would think this would be a good place to use guard, however the code is not as concise

```
func handleSomething(_ json: [String: Any]) -> Bool {
    let error = json["error"] as? String
    guard error == nil else {
        print("I have an error: \(error!)")
        return (false, error)
    }
    ...
    return (true, nil)
}
```

Is there a better way to do this so the assignment and check can be done in one line? If not is this the correct use of guard?

*Update:* Added return values to better illustrate the real intention of the question.

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32256911/771231

Comment: just keep the first variant and don't think too much about it.

Comment: No need to use guard and/or if conditional. Just return `json["error"] == nil`

Comment: Not all early exits need to be done with `guard`; using `if let` here is also the way I'd do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you should strongly avoid passing around `[String: Any]`. You should parse this down to a stronger data type earlier, and you should separate out error cases there, often with an enum:

```
struct ServerData {
    // good data; no errors
}

enum ServerResponse {
    case success(ServerData)
    case error(String) // Return this if error is set
}
```

With this, our functions would just take `ServerData` mostly, so errors have already been dealt with. Whenever possible, rather than coming up with clever workarounds to problems, make the whole problem go away.

That said, there's still the parser itself to deal with and this situation can come up both there and even when you have stronger types. In many cases you wind up with this guard/log pattern very often, and it's definitely worth avoiding that. So pull out a function:

```
func noErrorOrLog(_ json: [String: Any]) -> Bool {
    if let error = json["error"] as? String {
        print("I have an error: \(error)")
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Now actual handling functions can use `guard` and avoid duplicating the logging:

```
func handleSomething(_ json: [String: Any]) -> Bool {
    guard noErrorOrLog(json) else {
        return false
    }
    // ...
}
```

In some cases this doesn't make sense (if you're doing it exactly once perhaps), in which case `if-let` is the right tool. Creating confusing code to create a `guard` is counterproductive. But in many cases you can avoid this problem entirely (by filtering errors earlier with strong types), or avoid duplication by moving to a function.

Comment: I would agree this is better, however what if (and in my real code) I want to pass back the error code (using a return statement or callback). In my production code this is the earliest point the error can be handled (response from API)

Comment: Personally I'd probably use `throws` there, which makes a `try noErrorOrThrow(payload)` function very easy. No need for a guard.