# About guard let syntax

Tags: swift

```
let e: String? = "novel"
guard let f = e
else { return }
print(f)
```

i got error like below if I code like above

```
Playground execution failed:

error: dotinstall.playground:175:12: error: return invalid outside of a func
else { return }
```

I wanna use "guard let syntax " without "func()"

I tried it in some ways, but its wasn't worked well.I know almost the "guard let syntax " usually used with "func()".
But if I try it with "if let syntax " it was worked without error like below

```
let S: String? = "jjjj"
if let Thailand = S {
    print(Thailand)}
```

please show me how can I code with "guard let" without "func()"

Comment: You can use `fatalError()`, use anything that doesn't continue, use something like `break`, `return`, `continue`, `fatalError()`, or anything that returns `Never`, etc...

Comment: This error caused by ```return``` statement. This error is not related ```guard let```

Comment: See [`guard vs if-let`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39263210/5175709). Scroll down to *Guard requires scope exiting*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in playground:

```
guard let f = e else { fatalError("s is nil") }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

why it isn't worked if I put return in ()?

Comment: Because it is not a function. Return must be in a function, not in a top level code

Comment: @revoiot because you return from a function/method scope. Since there are none of them, Just a statement, You cannot return from the scope.

Comment: thank you very much!!! I solved the problem !!!