# Get output out of filter when there are no results

Tags: swift, swiftui, foundation

I was wondering, is there a way to get the result of a `filter` when there are no results?

At the moment, as a work around I have a ZStack and overlaying the results on top of a `"No results"` message.

But I was wondering if there was a conditional from the filter?

```swift
if(array.count > 0) {
  ForEach(array.filter({...}) { item in
    // do things if found
    //           <-- check if no results here
  }
} else {
  Text("No results at all")
}
```

I know that goes against the idea of the filtering, but thought I'd check in case I've missed something in all my searches!

Comment: you wouldn't even enter the scope if no element is to be found in the list filtered list. 
What you could do is `let filtered = array.filter({...})` and then `if(filtered.count) {...}` and loop over the variable instead. if you need distinction between no result and no filtered results you can add an `else if (array.count > 0) { /*no filtered results*/ }` followed by `else { /*no result at all*/ }`

Comment: Smart @Olympiloutre - thank you that made it very quick and easy :)

Comment: Your codes needs no improvement, having if- else is better to understand the code for another person reads your code.

Comment: @swiftPunk `guard else` is another option though, you could make it all seem sequential, it depends on what is to be done in each case. However, the guard statement tend to be mainly used with `guard let else` which doesn't achieve anything here. FFT though. @markb you're welcome!

Comment: @Olympiloutre: I know about `guard let else` or `guard else` but I do not know if you had experience of using it in SwiftUI, guard has issue with SwiftUI, and in some situation it well let you down, and it can gave you an unknown issue or error, the safest way is using `If let` not `guard let`

Comment: @swiftPunk thanks for the insight, I didn't have a chance to try SwiftUI yet, mainly because of this kind of rampants drawbacks. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if your **filtered** array in `if` is empty:

```
let filteredArray = array.filter({...})
if !filteredArray.isEmpty {
    ForEach(filteredArray) { item in
        // do things if found
    }
} else {
    Text("No results at all")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's answered already. But I want to add just one more change. Rather than using `if` better go with `guard` statement:

```
guard let filteredArray = array.filter({...}),
          !filteredArray.isEmpty else {
    Text("No results at all")
    return
}

ForEach(filteredArray) { item in
    // do things if found
}
```

You can read more about the difference here:

- [Swift: guard let vs if let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256834/swift-guard-let-vs-if-let)

Comment: Not sure if `guard` works inside a SwiftUI view

Comment: thanks! @aheze you can as long as it returns a View, at least it works for me :)

Comment: @markb yes but filter does not return an optional. You would need to use `guard case let`