# How to use OR for a value that can be nil?

Tags: swift

This is very basic but I'm kinda confused why my code isn't working. I have a `user` that has an optional `username` and I am trying to check whether the `email` or `username` contains my search query

```
struct ChatUser: Codable, Identifiable {
let email: String    
var username: String?
}

@State var user: ChatUser

if user.email.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased()) || 
user.username.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased()) {...}
```

It works if I unwrap `user.username!` but then my App crashes due to unwrapping nil values. How do I check for `user.username != nil` and then force unwrap in the if check?

Comment: Using ``if let`` or ``guard let`` to cover your optional value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256834/swift-guard-let-vs-if-let

Comment: May be it's `user.username!.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nil-coalescing(??)` to unwrap your optional value.

```
if user.email.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased()) || 
user.username?.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased()) ?? false {

}
```

Comment: Somehow I didn't think of this, instead I tried this `user.username! != nil ? user.username!.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased()) : user.email.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased())`

Comment: That is also correct but you need to add one more check, Also it is `user.username != nil` you need to remove `!`, otherwise it is still forced wrapping, so it will crash if username is nil

Comment: This answer is better, but it isn’t the answer that was accepted by the OP in the first place and it is getting close to another answer.  I usually only add to accepted answers in this case instead of changing them.  *Another was to do it is to use optional chaining like vadian suggested and then use nil-coalescing to unwrap the optional Bool*

Answer (score 3):

Calling `lowercased()` again and again is unnecessarily expensive.

But with your given syntax this is the *swifty* way

```
if user.email.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased()) || 
   user.username?.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased()) == true {...}
```

The *Optional Chaining* expression returns `nil` immediately if username is `nil`.

However `range(of:options:` can handle the optional **and** the case

```
if user.email.range(of: search, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil ||
    user.username?.range(of: search, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if user.email.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased()) || 
(user.username.map { $0.lowercased().contains(search.lowercased()) } ?? false) {

}
```

Comment: [Optional chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html)