# Swift 1.2 to 2.0 conversion - guard vs if let

Tags: ios, swift2, guard-statement

I am trying to convert some code from Swift 1.2 to 2.0. I have the below code in Swift 1.2

```
//enable OR disable keys.
if(discountAmountTextField.text.isEmpty){
    keypadView.disableNotRequiredKeys()
}else{
    keypadView.enableRequiredKeys()
}
```

There are two ways I can go about converting this to Swift 2.0 `guard` and `if let`

Here's how the code looks like with `if let`

```
//enable OR disable keys.
if let text = discountAmountTextField.text {
    if text.isEmpty {
        keypadView.disableNotRequiredKeys()
    } else {
        keypadView.enableRequiredKeys()
    }
} else {
    keypadView.enableRequiredKeys()
}
```

Here's how it looks using the guard syntax

```
//enable OR disable keys.
guard let text = discountAmountTextField.text else {
    keypadView.enableRequiredKeys()
    return;
}
if text.isEmpty {
    keypadView.disableNotRequiredKeys()
} else {
    keypadView.enableRequiredKeys()
}
```

I want to know what is considered as a more cleaner and appropriate way of writing. The guard looks cleaner to me but is there a rule of when I should be using one over the other? Is there any way to further simplify the method?

Comment: Use "if let ... where ...".

Comment: There is a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791488/swift-2-guard-keyword

Comment: "guard" is there to watch for conditions that shouldn't usually happen and handle them. So it looks quite inappropriate here.

Comment: @gnasher729 is right. Something like `if let text = discountAmountTextField.text where text.isEmpty { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: Changed it to `//enable OR disable keys.
        if let text = discountAmountTextField.text where text.isEmpty {
            keypadView.disableNotRequiredKeys()
        } else {
            keypadView.enableRequiredKeys()
        }` Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a `where` here:

```
if let text = discountAmountTextField.text where text.isEmpty {
    keypadView.disableNotRequiredKeys()
} else {
    keypadView.enableRequiredKeys()
}
```

It combines two of your failure cases into one.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid both, I guess.

You could rewrite your code like this:

```
switch discountAmountTextField.text?.isEmpty {
  case .Some(let value) where value:
      keypadView.disableNotRequiredKeys()
  case .Some(let value) where !value:
      keypadView.enableRequiredKeys()
  case _ :
      keypadView.enableRequiredKeys()
}
```

Compact, and still readable.

`guard` statements, in my opinion, are not the best when it comes to readability.

Also, as @gnasher729 suggests, this is not the best case to use it.

`if let` are slightly more readable, but you'll have to indent your code.

**Notes**

In my assumption:

`discountAmountTextField` is an instance of `UITextField`