# Value of optional Type "AnyObject?" not unwrapped did you mean to use ! or?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am receiving a JSON response from the server.

```
 do {
    let response = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,options:NSJSONReadinOptions.AllowFragments)
    let cityDetails  = reponse["cityDetails"]

    if cityDetails!.isKindOfClass(NSArray) {

    }
 }catch {
   println("Error \(error)")
 }
```

I get the following message

```
Value of optional Type "AnyObject?" not unwrapped did you mean to use ! or ??
```

The correction that I added later on was to use double !!. if `cityDetails!!.isKindOfClass(NSArray)`

Two questions to understand this are listed below?

1) Why to unrwap the object again even if its already un-wrapped once.

2) The below code is doing the same thing, but requires unwrapping only once. Also, it crashes because **result** happens to be nil.In Objectice C, nil is already handle and would return false in such case, instead of crashing the app. at that statement.

```
let testDictionary:[String:AnyObject] = ["a",NSMutableArray()]
let result = testDictionary["C"]

if result.isKindOfClass(NSArray) {

}
```

**Answers after input**
2) To solve the second issue i use the following Code.

**Approach 1**

```
if let _ = result {

    if result.isKindOfClass(NSArray) {

    }
}
```

**Approach 2**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let testDictionary:[String:AnyObject] = ["a":NSMutableArray()]

    let result = testDictionary["C"]

    print("Before details Check")
    guard let details = result where details.isKindOfClass(NSArray) else {
        return false
    }
    print("Returned Result \(details)")
    print("After Details Check")
    return true
}
```

Comment: No, you should unwrap the result using guard (**guard let result = result**) and then you can always safely call it.

Comment: Something went wrong statements after gaurd let details are not printed out

Comment: Replace result!.isKindOfClass(NSArray) with details.isKindOfClass(NSArray), which is the unwrapped value. But this should work I think, are you still having problems?

Comment: Yes. Before statements are called , but "after details check " is not printed out. Also, I tried the following but does not work guard let details = result where details.isKindOfClass(NSArray). I refered to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791488/swift-2-guard-keyword. Where gaurd has varaible name as the input.

Comment: What if you add print("Conversion failed") above return false. Does that print? If that's the case set a breakpoint for the debugger both at return false and return true, then you can see want details really is if it doesn't convert.

Comment: Yes it does print what's there in else{ }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93266/discussion-between-andypaul-and-departamento-b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unwrap values via **if let** or **guard let** statements:

```
guard let cityDetails = response["cityDetails"] as? NSArray else {
    // Something went wrong trying to turn response["cityDetails"] into an unwrapped NSArray
    return
}

// From this point cityDetails will be an unwrapped NSArray
```

Forced unwrapping of variables is a thing you should always try to avoid whenever possible.

The other snippet:

```
 guard let result = result  // Unwrap result
    where result.isKindOfClass(NSArray) else { // Ask the unwrapped value if it's an NSArray
    return // If one of above is not the case we shouldn't continue
}
```

Comment: Will it Crash if "cityDetails" is not Array, as in your answer its converting to NSArray

Comment: I don't know what you're getting exactly, you can see that in your debugger but I assumed it was NSArray as you used that as well. This is what happens: it will make sure that the constant cityDetails will contain a unwrapped NSArray for the key "cityDetails" in the response. If anything turns out to be null or not an NSArray you end up in the **else** clause. Using **if let** or **guard let** is always a bool returning true if it indeed was convertible. Always ask (as?) never force (as!) the conversion to not crash.