# Guard operation Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, guard-statement

I use Swift 2 and Xcode 7.

I would like to know the difference between

```
if condition { ... } else { ... }
```

and

```
guard ... else ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2 guard keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30791488/4151918)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The really big difference is when you are doing an optional binding:

```
if let x = xOptional {
    if let y = yOptional {
        // ... and now x and y are in scope, _nested_
    }
}
```

Contrast this:

```
guard let x = xOptional else {return}
guard let y = yOptional else {return}
// ... and now x and y are in scope _at top level_
```

For this reason, I often have a succession of multiple `guard` statements before I get to the meat of the routine.

Comment: And see my book for further discussion: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#SECguard

Comment: Here's a practical code example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/80551757899141e786b7f601f3879a7b450923c2/bk2ch02p070filters2/ch15p419filters/MyVignetteFilter.swift

Comment: And another (my code is full of this sort of thing): https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/80551757899141e786b7f601f3879a7b450923c2/bk2ch14p653backgroundPlayerAndInterrupter/interrupter/interrupter/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: `guard` also requires a `return`, `break` or something similar to exit the code block in which it occurs, where `if` statements don't. The compiler helps enforce the early-exit convention there.

Comment: @BradLarson And that is _why_ the binding is in scope at top level: if we get to the next line, we are guaranteed that the condition passed, i.e. we _didn't_ exit early, or we wouldn't be here at all.

Answer (score 2):

Like an `if` statement, `guard` executes statements based on a `Boolean` value of an expression. Unlike an `if` statement, `guard` statements only run if the conditions are not met. You can think of guard more like an `Assert`, but rather than crashing, you can gracefully exit.

Reference and code example [here](http://ericcerney.com/swift-guard-statement/).

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34006829/4151918), you can include several conditions in a single guard statement:

```
guard let x = xOptional, y = yOptional else { return }
// ... and now x and y are in scope _at top level_
```

In addition to optional binding, a guard condition can test boolean results:

```
guard x > 0 else { return }
```

In short, the benefit of the guard statement is to make the early exit apparent at the start of the scope, instead of the condition being buried further down in a nested else statement.