# What is basic difference between guard statement and if...else statement?

Tags: swift, swift2

I am confused about when to use `guard` and when to use `if...else`.

Is guard is replacement or alternative for If statement ?
Main thing want to know what are the functional benefits of `guard` statement for Swift language?

Any help to clear this situation will be appreciated.

Comment: Does [this prior Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791488/swift-2-guard-keyword) answer your question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using guard might not seem much different to using if, but with guard your intention is clearer: execution should not continue if your conditions are not met. Plus it has the advantage of being shorter and more readable, so guard is a real improvement, and I'm sure it will be adopted quickly.

There is one bonus to using guard that might make it even more useful to you: if you use it to unwrap any optionals, those unwrapped values stay around for you to use in the rest of your code block. For example:

```
   guard let unwrappedName = userName else {
return
}

print("Your username is \(unwrappedName)")
```

This is in comparison to a straight if statement, where the unwrapped value would be available only inside the if block, like this:

```
if let unwrappedName = userName {
print("Your username is \(unwrappedName)")
} else {
return
}

// this won't work – unwrappedName doesn't exist here!
print("Your username is \(unwrappedName)")
```

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift2

Comment: Second point for Unwrapped value scope is clear for me, but still not get How early return perform by guard statement when we have to check multiple conditions.